# SwiftUI: Distribute views within container evenly?

Tags: swiftui

Let's say I have a `ZStack` with an indeterminate/flexible width. There are four views within this `ZStack`. How would I distribute the views evenly... as if I were fanning out a deck of cards (*with each card overlapping the next*), like this:

[image: fan]

I can accomplish this effect with `.offset(x: ?)` if I know the width of the container:

```swift
ZStack {
    Text("One")
        .frame(width: 99, height: 150, alignment: .topLeading)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .offset(x: -99)
    Text("Two")
        .frame(width: 99, height: 150, alignment: .topLeading)
        .background(Color.red)
        .offset(x: -33)
    Text("Three")
        .frame(width: 99, height: 150, alignment: .topLeading)
        .background(Color.orange)
        .offset(x: 33)
    Text("Four")
        .frame(width: 99, height: 150, alignment: .topLeading)
        .background(Color.green)
        .offset(x: 99)
}
```

But what if I don't know the width of the container? Or what if it changes? Or what if the number of views within the container changes?

Basically, I just need to distribute views within the `ZStack` evenly... no matter what the width is. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have that many cards, you should use a `ForEach`. This will make adding/removing cards easier and saves some code.

> But what if I don't know the width of the container?

This is where [`GeometryReader`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader) comes in! You can use it to get the width of the container.

> I just need to distribute views within the ZStack evenly

Once you get the width from the `GeometryReader`, you can just divide by the number of elements in the cards array to calculate each card's width.

```
struct Card {
    var name: String
    var color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let cards = [
        Card(name: "One", color: .blue),
        Card(name: "Two", color: .red),
        Card(name: "Three", color: .orange),
        Card(name: "Four", color: .green)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                ForEach(cards.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    let card = cards[index]
                    
                    Text(card.name)                                             /// add a bit of overlap
                        .frame(width: proxy.size.width / CGFloat(cards.count) + 10, height: 150, alignment: .topLeading)
                        .background(
                            card.color
                                .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 5) /// make the overlap a bit more visible
                        )
                        .offset(x: proxy.size.width / CGFloat(cards.count) * CGFloat(index))
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) /// center the cards vertically
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Cards arranged evenly in horizontal row, with slight overlap]

Comment: Thanks. This works. SwiftUI gets pretty complicated, pretty fast.

Comment: @Sam true. But this is just 33 lines of code. No way you could do that in UIKit!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. create a function that returns `x` spacers (`x` for the number of text boxes that you want - 1) and inserts a `Text` view where you want it.
2. set the width to whatever you want it to be
3. have the text align to the left
4. replace all of the `Text` views in your code with this function

This should get the result you are looking for.